# Responsive triangle with css issue

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am making responsive triangle(down arrow) with css. My problem is  that I want to increase my triangle height downward But when I increase padding bottom it disturbs the triangle shape.

Here is my code :

```css
.btna {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  background-clip: content-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btna div {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d5adee, #fff);  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#d5adee, #fff);  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d5adee, #fff);  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#d5adee, #fff);  /* Standard syntax */
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 57.7%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="btna">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that you want to keep the triangle within the bounds of its .btna class, correct?

The following code retains a triangle while also making it so that it has more height and stays responsive.

Replace `transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);` with

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.4);
```

Skew can be very useful for making any triangle into a right triangle, but because we're all ready starting with one (the square with its overflow cut off), then it's not very helpful.